# How does one display the recursive search key in jq after a recursive search involving multiple keys?

Tags: jq

Given the following JSON:

```
{ 'doc': 'foobar',
  'pages': [
       { 'data': { 'keyA': { 'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar' }, 'keyB': {'A':'123', 'B': 'c'} }, 
       ...
   ]
}
```

I am performing the following `jq` search:

```
#!/usr/bin/jq -f

.. | .keyA?, .keyB?
```

Which is great:

```
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'} # pretend it is formatted
{'A': '123', 'B': 'c'}
```

But now I'd like to format the output like:

```
{'key': 'keyA', 'value': {...}}
{'key': 'keyB', 'value': {...}}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to use the recursive operator `..` and do this.

Instead, I'll have to run N-independent searches for the N keys to have them all separated out. This is painful.

Is it possible to reform the data so that the output of the search function gets labeled with the key that yielded the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_entries` will turn an object into an array of key-value pairs. Then, checking the key name explicitly enables you to also find values of `null`. The `-c` flag makes the output "compact".

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -c -f

.. | objects | to_entries[] | select(.key == ("keyA", "keyB"))
```

```json
{"key":"keyA","value":{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}}
{"key":"keyB","value":{"A":"123","B":"c"}}
```

Comment: can you explain how you constructed the hash-bang? I see a `-S` there I don't understand...

Comment: @Chris From `man env`: `The -S option allows specifying multiple parameters in a script.`. It basically enables you to provide more than just one parameter, such as `-c` in this case.